# Store table in memory (ArrayList?)

Tags: vba

I would like to store list in memory to be able to use it later to retrieve a value based on search result.

Data to be stored in memory:

```
Audi     45
BMW      34
Toyota   28
Lincoln  78
Maserati 124
```

I am performing search by another code and get as a result, lets say `BMW`. Can somebody provide an example how to get as an output `34`?

I can add items to ArrayList, but how to get equivalent value out?

```
Sub CarList()

    Dim coll As Object
    Set coll = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    ' Add items
    coll.Add "Audi" 
    coll.Add "BMW"
    coll.Add "Toyota"
    coll.Add "Lincoln"
    coll.Add "Maserati"

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use an ArrayList, use Scripting.Dictionary. Scripting.Dictionaries manage Key,Value pairs so you would retrieve the value 34 using coll.Item("BMW").  Scripting.Dictionaries have an advantage over a collection in that you can change the value of the Item if you need to.

Comment: I have used Scripting.Dictionary. You can add your comment as an answer. Thank you for suggestion!

Comment: Comment now posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an ArrayList, use a Scripting.Dictionary. Scripting.Dictionaries manage Key,Value pairs so you would retrieve the value 34 using coll.Item("BMW"). Scripting.Dictionaries have an advantage over a collection in that you can change the value of the Item if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The late binding approach (shown by freeflow) will serve you well, usually.

However, an early binding approach (by including reference "Microsoft Scripting Runtime") could be better, depending on the scale of the calculation. If using early binding, then the script looks more readable; and it should be faster.

```
Dim Car_List As Scripting.Dictionary
Set Car_List = New Scripting.Dictionary
Call Car_List.Add("audi", 45)
Call Car_List.Add("Austin Healey 3000", 1967)
```